# Display/Print both full content and teaser in node.tpl

Tags: theming, nodes

I want to display both full content and teaser content at the same time in node.tpl.php Here is an example of what i want to display

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#mini" data-toggle="tab">Mini Table</a></li>
    <li><a href="#full" data-toggle="tab">Full Table</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="table-tab" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="mini">
        TEASER DISPLAY
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="full">
        FULL CONTENT DISPLAY
    </div>
</div>
```

I search for it but didn't find the answers. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be worked for you.

for teaser use

```
$rendered_teaser = render(node_view(node_load($node->nid), 'teaser'));
print $rendered_teaser;
```

and for full use

```
$rendered_full = render(node_view(node_load($node->nid), 'full'));
print $rendered_full;
```